# Prevent copy on an empty iFrame (GWT RichTextArea)

Tags: javascript, gwt, iframe, event-handling, rich-text-editor

I am required to prevent copy from a form. Using a `oncopy` handler works just fine on all `<input/>`-type fields.

Yet I fail to apply it to our "richtextarea", which is basically an empty iframe (`src="about:blank"` for what I have been able to gather; the page is GWT-generated, and the people before me developped quite an extensive framework around it).

I am able to get the iframe in the JavaScript, but I fail to have a correct handler (I tried adding one that logs, but it never does).

I have tried `frame.oncopy`, `frame.contentWindow.oncopy`, `frame.contentWindow.document.oncopy`, `frame.contentDocument.oncopy`. None of these does log to the console when I copy the iframe's content.

Does somebody have any lead for me? Any help appreciated (I've been stuck on this for some days now).

Having a cross-compatible solution would of course be ideal, but the main target is Firefox (the page is only open via a custom container based on Firefox 10).

**Edit 2015-03-24**

For those who want to try some debug script, the component I have trouble with is the one demonstrated [here](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~RichTextArea).

I have some `native` methods in the Java project to execute some custom JavaScript on it.

Below is some of the JavaScript I have unsuccessfully tried.

```
var frame = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

function disallowCopy() {
    alert('Gotcha!');
    return false;
}

frame.oncopy = disallowCopy;
frame.contentWindow.oncopy = disallowCopy;
frame.contentWindow.document.oncopy = disallowCopy;
frame.contentWindow.document.body.oncopy = disallowCopy;
frame.contentDocument.oncopy = disallowCopy;
```

Answer (score 1):

even though `oncopy` is a non standard event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/oncopy and that there is no reliable way to prevent copying text,

you can check out the following [bin](http://jsbin.com/bacuwediqo/1/edit?html,js,output)

1. ensure the frame is loaded
2. use `iframe.contentDocument.body` to attch the event

Comment: I had no idea [`oncopy`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oncopy.asp) was not standard. I am  adapting some existing code.

Still, your bin does succeed in _catching_ the event (the `iframe.contentDocument.body` is what I have been searching for for a few days), but does not prevent the text from being added to the clipboard (even when I add the [propagation stop](http://jsbin.com/qayakupono/1/edit) we have for `<input />` elements).

I think this problem will be put to rest for now, but am interested if any news come up. Thanks for the help, krampstudio.

Comment: If you want to prevent all user interactions including copying, another way would be to add a transparent overlay above the content you want to protect.

Comment: I saw this solution indeed in my previous searches, and it is quite efficient. Yet, in our case, you can have a combination of editable and copy disallowed, so I cannot apply this. Just out of curiousity: when using an overlay, you should also think of preventing accessing the iframe with the `Tab` key, right?

Comment: You can prevent the focus on the element using the HTML attribute `tabindex="-1"`. But for your use case, I would say that if a field is editable, then we can copy/paste. Another possibility would be to prevent text selection using the CSS property `user-select: none;` but I don't know if it works for fields and it can be disappointing to edit a field but can't select it's content.

Comment: The logic of the use-case can be discussed, but that is not my place right now. Something was not working, and I wanted to fix it, without breaking other use-cases I might not be aware of, therefore without changing the general behavior. The pieces of information were interesting for a general case, too bad it did not work out for GWT.